# How to send push notification by using php to android

Tags: php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to send push notification to my app from PHP server.
but I don't understand certain thing like what I need to make PHP server.
I have my app. I configured every thing.
I have created my app in phonegap.
I have API KEY, Project NO., and Registration Key.

I have follow this articles:

[Google Cloud Messaging GCM for Android and Push Notifications](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)

[Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

[Push notifications with PhoneGap and Android](http://gielberkers.com/push-notifications-phonegap-android/)

but still not able to create php page to send notifications.
I can send notification using pushbots.
but I want to create my own PHP page to send Push notification.
Please help me with this.
I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What PHP code you've tried so far?

Comment: The One which is in article : Google Cloud Messaging GCM for Android and Push Notifications

Comment: Where do you encounter a problem? What are the errors you're getting? We can't help you based on "it doesn't work".

Comment: Have you tried following the answer?

Answer (score 0):

For a good example of PHP code that send Android push notification [look at this gist](https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017).

In order to have always the updated version of registration tokens, you should write another php page that receive tokens from devices and write them in a db. Then you can get these tokens before sending push notifications.